# Detecting Time Deltas Between Furnace On & Furnace Off

Tags: python, sql

I have a database table that stores temperatures of the output air from a furnace. Each row has a timestamp (ms) and temperature (degF). To capture some usage metrics on the system I am trying to write sql or python to do the following

A) Detect the time in ms for the period where temperature is rising (system is on) 
B) Detect the time in ms for the period where temperature values are decreasing (system is off)

Ideally i'm trying to get each heating period measured e.g. On for 12 minutes, off for 28 mins, on for 14 mins etc.

Sample data is below..

```
timestamp | F
1544154123|117.28
1544154063|116.15
1544154003|112.66
1544153943|107.26
1544153883|99.84
1544153823|92.08
1544153763|93.2
1544153703|104.79
1544153643|115.81
1544153584|116.83
1544153523|113.67
1544153463|109.17
1544153404|102.99
1544153343|94.66
1544153283|89.26
1544153223|98.94
1544153163|110.86
1544153103|115.7
1544153043|112.1
1544152983|106.7
1544152923|98.26
1544152863|85.55
1544152803|72.61
```

my code to where I am now confused..

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import os
import glob
import time
import sqlite3 as lite
import re
import requests
import json
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import traceback

# Import settings.

try:
    from settings import settings
except ImportError:
    from default_settings import settings

try:
    con = lite.connect(settings['db'])
    db = con.cursor()
    timestamp = int(time.time())
    db.execute('SELECT Timestamp, F from Temperature where DeviceID = 3 ORDER by Timestamp DESC limit 100'
               )

    rows = db.fetchall()

    lastValue = 0
    latestValue = 0
    firstrun = True

    refTime = datetime.datetime(2200, 9, 16, 0, 0)
    increasingTime = datetime.datetime(1978, 9, 16, 0, 0)
    decreasingTime = datetime.datetime(1978, 9, 16, 0, 0)

    periods = {}

    waitingForRise = False
    waitingForFall = False

    for row in rows:
        state = ''
        ts = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(row[0]))

   # .strtime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        latestValue = row[1]

   # we capture time between the event where it transitions from inc to dec

        if firstrun == True:
            lastValue = latestValue
            firstrun = False
            decreasing = True
            waitingForRise = True
            waitingForFall = False
        elif latestValue <= lastValue:

                                  # decreasing

            if waitingForFall == True and decreasingTime < refTime:  # going down, expecting a down but not stored it yet
                waitingForFall = False  # no longer waiting for a fall
                decreasingTime = ts  # store the edge point
            else:

          # going down, do nothing, just reinforce we need to wait

                waitingForFall = True
        elif latestValue > lastValue:

                                 # increasing

            if waitingForRise == True and increasingTime < refTime:

                waitingForRise = False  # on the way down, lets record the next up
            else:
                print 'transition Down to Up -> ' + str(lastValue) \
                    + '->' + str(latestValue)
                increasingTime = ts
                waitingForFall = True
                waitingForRise = False

        lastValue = latestValue
except:

   # print ts + " > " + str(row[1]) + " > " + state

    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print e
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: sqlite is the db..

Comment: Show what have you tried (code-wise) so far.

Comment: Here's what I have.. so far.. honestly I'm self taught.. and I can't figure out the tracking of the up and down

Comment: What version of SQLite?  To be honest, although this *can* be done in SQLite, the query is much more complicated than necessary, unless you are using version 3.25 or later.

Comment: What about the first record in the series, is it rising or decreasing ? What if two or more  consecutive records have the same value, are they rising or decreasing ?